# How to save pictures to document with Python win32com

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I am making html to doc converter

> > from win32com.client import Dispatch
> >     wrd=Dispatch('Word.Application')
> >     doc=wrd.Documents.Open(inputfile)
> >     doc.SaveAs(outputfile, FileFormat=0)
> >     doc.Close

And I wand save picture to document: Prepare->Edit links to file->Save picture to document

What command I need?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJOS7.png

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture%28office.11%29.aspx) method in the [InlineShapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms263924%28v=Office.11%29.aspx) collection.

> ```
> FileName
> ```
>
> Required String. The path and file name of the picture.
>
> ```
> LinkToFile
> ```
>
> Optional Object. True to link the picture to the file from which it
>   was created. False to make the picture
>   an independent copy of the file. The
>   default value is False.
>
> ```
> **SaveWithDocument**
> ```
>
> Optional Object. True to save the linked picture with the document.
>   The default value is False.
>
> ```
> Range
> ```
>
> Optional Object. The location where the picture will be placed in
>   the text. If the range isn't
>   collapsed, the picture replaces the
>   range; otherwise, the picture is
>   inserted. If this argument is omitted,
>   the picture is placed automatically.